# Spring Controller: bind query parameters to custom POJO fields

Tags: java, spring, pojo, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to map certain values from request query parameters to POJO parameters as the following.
This is the POJO:

```
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    @NotNull(message = "personId cannot be null")
    @Min(value = 0)
    private Long personId;

    @NotNull(message = "from date cannot be null")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime from;

    @NotNull(message = "to date cannot be null")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime to;

    private Map<String, String> filters;
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/persons")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> getPersons(@Valid final Person personRequest) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.getPersonsCount(personRequest));
    }
```

I want to map request query parameters to the attributes of this pojo. This is the expected request:

```
{application_url}/persons?personId=12&from=2017-03-22T00:00:00&to=2019-03-22T00:00:00&country=UK&company=xyz
```

I want to map `personId, from, to` to corresponding attributes in POJO and map the rest of query parameters `nationality, company` to the filters map. In other words `personId, to, from` are only static in the request and the rest of the parameters may vary, we can have `salary=1000&minAage=31` instead of `country=UK&company=xyz` so I want to map the rest of the parameters to the `filters` map.

Is there a way to achieve so?

Comment: @Eklavya, it's a GET request and required to be as query parameters.

Comment: Use `@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams`  to get all request param then prepare `Person`  from `requestParams` map manually

Comment: I see your point but I was wondering if there is more direct way to achieve this.

Comment: May be not possible and it's logical

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you create and hook in your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Take a look at `RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver` - which is how it converts query parameters into a map as Eklavya mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can achieve it is to use `@RequestParam Map<String, String> filters` with other request parameters or just to use map for request parameters. Because all parameters would be included in map.

---

### Example with all parameters in request:

```
@GetMapping(path = "persons")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getPersons(@RequestParam Long personId,
                                          @RequestParam String from,
                                          @RequestParam String to,
                                          @RequestParam Map<String, String> filters) {
    Person person = Person.builder()
            .personId(personId)
            .from(getDate(from))
            .to(getDate(to))
            .filters(filterMap(filters))
            .build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.getPersonsCount(person));
}

private LocalDateTime getDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
}

private Map<String, String> filterMap(Map<String, String> request) {
    request.remove("personId");
    request.remove("from");
    request.remove("to");
    return request;
}
```

The code is totally messed up. And since `Map<String, String> filters` is `@RequestParam`, so it includes all request parameters even what's defined above. So you need to remove `pesonId`, `from`, `to` if you don't want to be in `filters` map.

### Example with request map only

```
@GetMapping(path = "persons")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getPerson(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams) {
    Person person = Person.builder()
             .personId(Long.valueOf(requestParams.get("personId")))
             .from(getDate(requestParams.get("from")))
             .to(getDate(requestParams.get("to")))
             .filters(filterRequest(requestParams))
             .build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.getPersonsCount(person));
}

private LocalDateTime getDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
}

private Map<String, String> filterRequest(Map<String, String> request) {
    request.remove("personId");
    request.remove("from");
    request.remove("to");
    return request;
}
```

---

However at least I don't know nice or simple configuration to convert path parameters to POJO before calling controller endpoint, so I suggest you to use something from these examples. Otherwise use request body or try to use this [example](https://www.javatips.net/api/spring-reactive-master/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver.java)

Comment: I see it's the easiest solution for this case as mention also by @Eklavya above.

Comment: Good writing! @m.y.m It's not possible the way you think because you can't map `a map` into a single query param. Hope you understand.